# CORS - Cookie not getting set

Tags: jquery, ajax, cookies, cors

I am building a web-app which uses CORS. When I do a GET call to the CORS domain, both in Chrome and Firefox I can see in the Network tab there are "Set-Cookie" headers and also when I go to the "Cookies" tab (in the Network view) I can see the cookies sent by the server. However when I go to the Resources tab I don't see the cookies getting set. Also, when I make a subsequent call to the same server (CORS call) the cookies are not being sent as a part of the Request Headers. I have done the following:

- setting the withCredentials = true when the Ajax call is being made

  ```
  $.ajax({
      url : "https://cors.com/",           
      type : "GET",
      crossDomain : true,
      dataType: "json",
      withCredentials: true,
      beforeSend : function(xhr) {
          // do soemthing..
      },
      success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
          // do soemthing
      },
      error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          // do something 
      }
  });
  ```
- the CORS server sets the Access-Control-Allow-Credentals: true

Any ideas as to what I am missing here ?

Comment: Are you making the CORS call from an unsecure (http) page? Since you are calling a secure (https) endpoint, the cookie won't be accessible from unsecure pages and the resources tab might not show it.

Comment: The client also uses https..

Comment: @mithrandir did you solve this issue?  I'm having similar problems.